# ArrayAdapter data List is always empty although it's full in the AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I'm fetching all songs on the device in an AsyncTask. When I `Log` all songs in the `songs` List variable in the `AsyncTask` they all show up. But when I `Log` them in the constructor of the `ArrayAdapter`, it's always empty. How is this even possible?

The AsyncTask:

```
private class SongFinder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, null, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "Fetching next batch of songs");
        if (cursor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to discover songs",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "No media on device",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cursor.getString(0);
                String title = cursor.getString(2);
                String artist = cursor.getString(1);
                String data = cursor.getString(3);
                String albumName = cursor.getString(8);
                Long albumId = cursor.getLong(6);
                String albumKey = cursor.getString(7);

                songs.add(new Song(id, title, artist, data, albumName,
                        albumKey, albumId));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
                // HERE IT'S FULL WITH THE SONGS I WANT
        Log.d(TAG, songs.toString());
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (songs.size() > 0) {

                            //HERE IT IS ALWAYS EMPTY
            Log.d(TAG, songs.toString());
            SongArrayAdapter adapter = new SongArrayAdapter(activity, songs);
            EndlessSongAdapter songAdapter = new EndlessSongAdapter(activity,
                    adapter, R.layout.arrayadapter_songs);
            songsList.setAdapter(songAdapter);
            songsList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            songsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> root, View view,
                        int position, long when) {

                    Intent newSong = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_NEW);
                    newSong.putExtra("song", songs.get(position));
                    Log.i(TAG, "sending broadcast");
                    bManager.sendBroadcast(newSong);

                    // Reset the play/pause button.
                    activity.resetButton();

                    Intent addSong = new Intent(
                            "com.xx.xx.ADDSONG");
                    addSong.putExtra("song", songs.get(position));
                    bManager.sendBroadcast(addSong);
                    activity.fragmentChangeNewSong();
                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Calling the AsyncTask

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    activity = (MusicActivity) getActivity();
    bManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity);
    ListView songsList = getListViewWithSongs(activity);
    return songsList;
}

public ListView getListViewWithSongs(final MusicActivity activity) {
    songsList = new ListView(activity);
    new SongFinder().execute();

    return songsList;
}
```

So the `private List<Song> songs` variable is filled in the `doInBackground()` method of the AsyncTask, but it's empty in the `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: First off, this looks like you are offloading the reading of the cursor to an async task. Don't you want to also offload the actual query? That is the part that usually takes time (especially since you are just pulling simple string data). Second, do you get two print outs? Your code suggests the second print statement just prints empties. What is the output of the log for that tag? and How are you starting the async task

Comment: If you could point out how to do this `offloading` like it should be, I would appreciate it. The first print out is like you would expect. I see the debug Log. But the second one doesn't get called it seems. When I call it it in the `SongArrayAdapter` constructor, it's empty. Looks like the `onPostExecute()` is skipped?

Comment: Well I mean the cursor comes from somewhere. I assume you ask a content provider or `SQLiteDatabase` to `query()`. This should also be in the `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`. This is why I want to see how you use the async task

Comment: `while (cursor.moveToNext()) { /*...*/ }` <= you know that you're skipping first row ?

Comment: I edited the code for offloading the `Cursor`. Also, Selvin, thanks for pointing that out! I added the AsyncTask decleration too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I actually figured it out. Another `Fragment` was being loaded simultaneously that also uses the `EndlessSongAdapter` and that was crashing it. When I commented it all, all the other code were able to run and finish, without crashing.... Really stupid mistake. The LogCat was actually not showing in the Stack trace from which fragment class it was being called, so I never figured it out

So if you run into the same problem, check if your `ViewPager` is loading multiple `Fragments` and if they can possible create a "collision"

Answer (score 1):

So, the critical thing I'm seeing you're missing (without having seen the rest of the application), is a call to:

```
songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This assumes, of course that your adapter extends BaseAdapter.    Without that call, the adapter has no way to know that the list has been updated.  So, it's a good idea to always call 'notifyDataSetChanged()' whenever you update the list.

You can also use a CursorAdapter if you like, and the view should call the cursor to get data automatically.  Your mileage will vary with that, however, because if the queries to the cursor are too slow, the user interface will slow down.

Here are a couple of other thoughts:

1. in `onPostExecute` you are creating a new adapter every time. This isn't necessary. This works, but is not necessary. You can simply clear out the private list `songs` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter.
2. You're setting the on click listener every time when you call `songsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()`.  This also is un-necessary. You can set the click listener in onCreate or onResume.

These are small details, but they add up to important things.  Every time you create a new object and assign it to a variable/member, the object that it replaces is marked for garbage collection unless it's being referenced somewhere else in your program.  If you do this too much, the garbage collector will start to work overtime and slow down your application - especially if you're running your `SongFinder` task a lot.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for these tips, but they do not answer the question so I can't accept this. I've been removing lots of lines to figure out what's wrong. I also removed to `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I of course have to add it in again.

Comment: I don't see the code from the ArrayAdapter.  If you post that perhaps I can help more.

Comment: Is it that the Logcat output is not showing, or is it that the list is not getting populated ?

Comment: Well I actually figured it out. Another `Fragment` was being loaded simultaneously that also uses the `EndlessSongAdapter` and that was crashing it. When I commented it all, all the other code were able to run and finish, without crashing.... Really stupid mistake. The `LogCat` was actually not showing in the Stack trace from which fragment class it was being called, so I never figured it out.